# Determining and interpreting the critical region of a distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, critical-value

Suppose that you have a null hypothesis $H_0$ that you want to test. Let $\alpha$ be a given confidence level, for example $\alpha = 0.05$. Suppose that the test statistic $T$ follows (under $H_0$) a $\chi^2$ distribution, say $T \sim \chi^2 (4)$.

In my understanding, the critical region of a distribution means a set of 'rare' values of $T$ in the sense that
$$ \mathbb{P}\left[T \in \text{critical region}\right]=\alpha. $$
How should one choose the critical region? I guess that, in the case of this $\chi^2 (4)$ distribution, one typically chooses a critical value $t_0>0$ such that
$$\mathbb{P}[T\ge t_0] = \alpha, $$
and thus the critical region would be $[t_0, +\infty)$. However, when you look at the distribution, the values of $T$ very close zero are rare as well; the pdf is continuous and has value 0 at 0. Thus, it would be tempting to determine two critical values $t_0$ and $t_1$ such that
$$ \mathbb{P} [T \le t_0 \text{ or } T \ge t_1 ] = \alpha,$$
and choose the critical region to be $[0, t_0] \cup [t_1, +\infty)$. Is there a rule of thumb, or is this just a matter of taste?

Comment: You are correct, there are (potentially infinitely) many ways of defining a critical region. Usually you would base your choice on trying to maximize the  [power of the test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_test) against a certain alternative hypothesis.

Comment: "Let α be a given confidence level" -- you mean *significance level* there.  You might like to consider which values of $T$ are most indicative of the alternative and put your rejection region there (you want to reject when the data most strongly suggest $H_1$, not when they don't). Then if you consider a sequence of $\alpha$ values, and the fact that it would be useful to nest your rejection regions (RRs for lower alpha nested inside those for higher alpha), these considerations tend to quickly resolve things.

Comment: ... The nesting is useful because the converse situation is incongruous. If a specific value of the test statistic ($T=t$) would lead you to reject at some $\alpha=\alpha_1$ you *also* want that same value ($t$) to be rejected at some higher significance level $\alpha_2>\alpha_1$. This desirable property is that nesting.